# Imagen de fondo en App Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Quiero poner una imagen de fondo, de hecho se ponerla pero no respeta la proporción y queda muy alargada. Como las dimensiones de los dispositivos móviles son muy variadas, me gustaría que la imagen no se deformara y se cortase donde acabe la pantalla ya que el tamaño es superior (1920x1080).

Y así empieza mi layout: (background es background.png, el fondo).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Inicio">
```

¿Cómo me aconsejan hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Me auto contesto.

He creado un xml a parte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

Y es este xml el que coloco en el background del layout y listo :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821121/set-background-image-for-all-screen-size